# Http request --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Tags: javascript, http, nginx, httprequest

Now ,i encounter a case.

This period of time，my website is very slow some time(Only one request，so it would not be request blocking).

I observe that when the page runs slowly,it ‘s timing performance as [image]

And  i open chrome://net-internals/#events, find the result:

[image]

what 's wrong? what happened in the time between t(29) and t(18933)?

dns lookup? nginx queueing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fact is that you don't have **only one request** to the server.

1. Even if you have the web page open in a single tab, there might be multiple connections for different resources.
2. If you are using a proxy server, then all the requests go to the proxy server, causing requests to block.

---

Read the answer to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740692/request-stalled-for-a-long-time-occasionally-in-chrome/29732252#29732252):

> The cause of the problem is multiple simultaneous connections to the
>   server. Every browser has a limit to the maximum number of TCP
>   connections to a server. For chrome, the limit is six. The problem is
>   more prominent when you are using a proxy server, because all the
>   requests go the same server (the proxy server).
>
> Chrome doesn't allow you to change this limit. It shouldn't in fact.
>   If you want to know more about why this limit exists, and what are the
>   limits for other browsers, you can read [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/).
>
> The reason why this limit is rarely a problem is because multiple HTTP
>   requests to the same host are mostly sent consecutively, rather than
>   parallely, preferably over the same TCP connection.
>
> If this problem occurs to you frequently, then the reason might be:
>
> 1. **Server doesn't support persistent TCP connection:** If the problem occurs only when accessing a particular server, the reason
>      might be that chrome is fetching multiple resources (like images, CSS
>      files, etc) on parallel connections. Since, in your case, the server
>      is on your local network, you might want to ask the server's
>      administrator to add support for persistent TCP connections.
> 2. **Multiple persistent connections are open:** If you are working behind a proxy server, then downloading multiple files simultaneously
>      or opening sites which keep a TCP connection open might be the cause
>      of your problem.To get rid of it, all you can do is to not download
>      many things simultaneously (or download in a different browser, if you
>      have to).
>
> **PS:** The error **net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)** is because of the timeout, waiting for some previous connection to the
>   server to close.